# listview is not displaying in android API 16 version.but not dispalying under versions.how can i fix this?

Tags: android, xml

This is xml code of my layout.its not displaying in API16 but its working properly in API
23,but its not working under versions.notging to display.

```
   <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_primary"> 
   </ListView>
   <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text14"
                android:text="Taken"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

     <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text16"
                android:text="Skip"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dismiss"
                android:id="@+id/text15"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
   </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/btn1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_taken" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/btn2"
                android:id="@+id/btnskip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="-70dp"
                />



                <Button
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/btn3"
                    android:id="@+id/btndismiss"
                   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-70dp"
                    />


        </LinearLayout>
```

list_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listview">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/logback">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/label_medname"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Medicine Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_mediname"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logback">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label_quan"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Quantity               :"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_quantity"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logback">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label_when"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="When                    :"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_when"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="When"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

how can i fix this?
 every thing is exactly same but data is not displaying in the list. Please i'm badly stuck here and i really need some fast help. Waiting for some positive response !

Comment: Any error? share your logcat

Comment: no errors in logcat

Comment: are you using custom adapter for listview?

Comment: post your list item xml and adapter code